# Upgrading Subversion server from 1.5.5 to 1.6.5 - dump/upgrade/reload, exact steps?

Tags: svn, upgrade

I'm about to upgrade a SVN server from version 1.5.5 to 1.6.5 - all is fine with the actual upgrade, but I'm a little confused about upgrading the actual repositories.

I've read in a few places ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160761/how-to-upgrade-svn-1-4-4-r25188-to-svn-1-6/1161408#1161408), [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.upgrade.html)), that it's better to dump and reload the repositories rather than using `svnadmin upgrade`. I assume that I should dump, upgrade the server and then load the dumps back in - however, should I clear the old files out of the repository before loading? If so, what's the best way to do this?

If, before I thoroughly screw up my version control system, someone could give me a quick step-by-step, it would be really helpful!

Cheers, 
Mark

Answer (score 11, accepted):

there is a [quick step-by-step](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#dumpload) in the Subversion FAQ:

> 1. Shut down svnserve, Apache, and anything else that might be accessing the repository.
> 2. `svnadmin dump /path/to/repository > dumpfile.txt` , using version X of svnadmin.
> 3. `mv /path/to/repository /path/to/saved-old-repository`
> 4. Now upgrade to Subversion Y (i.e., build and install Y, replacing X).
> 5. `svnadmin create /path/to/repository`, using version Y of svnadmin.
> 6. `svnadmin load /path/to/repository < dumpfile.txt` , again using version Y of svnadmin.
> 7. Copy over hook scripts, etc, from the old repository to the new one.
> 8. Restart svnserve, Apache, etc.

[more details on dumping and loading](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) in the Subversion book. i assume you studied the [subversion 1.6 release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html).

Comment: Yep, I've checked the release notes - thanks though, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Beware, those dumps are big. You *could* use the --deltas option with svn dump, which will somewhat reduce your dump file size. It is slower though, and alternatively you could gzip the dumps on the fly (without --deltas) which will be even more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not need to dump/load to upgrade, 1.6 was specifically designed to be an easy upgrade using just `svnadmin upgrade`. I've done it, it worked, I am happy.

The [release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html) explicitly say there is no need to dump/load the repo.

I would make a backup anyway (just in case), and then do the recommended upgrade. I'd then pack the repo files (`svadmin pack`) to make future backups quicker and SVN perform faster.

Comment: the release notes also say (http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.6_releasenotes.html#bdb-forward-deltas): "If you want to achieve the most optimized state of an older [BDB] repository, you still need to perform dump and load of the repository." also see the links in the question.

Comment: Nobody should use a BDB repo. If you do, you still need to dump and load the repo.... into a FSFS one :)

Comment: In 1.9 a dump-reload is again not required, but it is necessary to achieve  optimal state i.e. smaller disk usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do it that way then you probably want to dump, upgrade, delete and recreate the repo then load it back in again.

I can't say I've ever had any issues just using upgrade though, although you may end up with a less optimal repo structure.

Comment: So, would you suggest that I may as well just use upgrade?

Comment: Unless it's a particularly big or complicated repo that's what I'd do. Dump and load can take a long time.

Comment: I agree. However, you should nevertheless make sure you have a backup before you upgrade. Making a dump is one way to create a backup.

Comment: Of course, but I would hope his svn is already being backed up regularly :-)